# Getting a have DNS error

Tags: domain-name-system

Im getting this message "Apache is working on your cPanel® and WHM™ Server" the thing is all the files are on "WINDOWS SERVER 2003" which is a VPS.

I tried for two day to fix this, with no luck I run a report on http://www.intodns.com/essexdrugaction.org and it show a DNS servers responded error

Can someone tell me how to fix it please.

Comment: The DNS error is unrelated to the default Apache/cPanel page showing up.  Show your DNS provider that intodns page or switch provider.  To help fix the cPanel priblem we will need to know more about what sites you have configured.  If in doubt, more detail is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question isn't worded very clearly, but the error you get back when you use that link is just that one of the three DNS servers isn't responding.  It doesn't stop people resolving the domain name into a working IP address.

Your issue appears to be incorrectly configured hosting.  I suggest you speak to your hosting company and have them walk you through setting it up correctly.

Comment: Turned out we had to wait a bit longer for everything to propagate after changing the IP address funny how inpatients can make things worst.